# Meteor - How can I find/get an object in a MongoDB collection and push it into another collection with a method?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, methods, collections, push

I have a server side method like:

```
Meteor.methods({ 
 'pushInfo': function(){
   if (this.userId) {
    userManagement.update({
    '_id': this.userId
    }, {
     $push: {
     'activeInfos': ["The Info/Object I want to push from another collection"]
      }
     }
    );
   }
  }
});
```

This method should push an object into the field 'activeInfos' inside the collection 'userManagement'.

I have a `click.` event which triggers the method like:

```
Template.available.events({
 "click. push": function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Meteor.call('pushInfo');
 }
});
```

Now, I have another collection called 'Infos' from where I want to push the single objects/ID´s into the field 'activeInfos' via the method.

The method works like expected when I manually fill it with an ID from the 'Infos'-collection. It pushes this ID into 'activeInfos' and the user can now access this objectID from 'Infos'.

However, it should automatically find the right ID from 'Infos' and push it into 'activeInfos', when the method is triggered.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How to get the right ID as your said?

Comment: yes, some kind of like:    Infos.find({"_id": ...}).fetch[0]._id function maybe?  And to put it so, that it will be pushed via the method.

Answer (score 0):

If your `available` template is showing a list of `Infos` then you can get the `_id` of the `Infos` object in your event handler and pass it to the method:

```
Template.available.events({
  "click. push"(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('pushInfo',this.InfoId);
  }
});


Meteor.methods({ 
  'pushInfo'(infoId)=>{
    const info = Infos.findOne(infoId)
    if (this.userId && info) {
      userManagement.update(this.userId, { $push: { activeInfos: info }});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I receive an error while loading the localhost "unexpected token =>".

Comment: I was guessing that you had a collection in the data context but didn't know what key you were using. From your answer below it looks like you used `InfoId` to refer to the object. Code changed above.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! However, thanks for your effort! I don´t know why, but I just had to assign this.InfoId to a var and put InfoId into the Meteor.call within the event handler. Than I was able to pass this var into the function within the server side method and grab it for the $push.

```
Template.available.events({
"click .push": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var InfoId = this.InfoId;
    Meteor.call('pushInfo', InfoId);
}, });
```

and

```
 Meteor.methods({
  'pushInfo': function(InfoId) {
    if (this.userId) {
      userManagement.update({
          '_id': this.userId
        }, {
          $push: {
            'activeInfos': infoId
          }
        } 
      );
    }
  }
});
```